# Why observable method is called each time where component is placed?

Tags: angular

I have a custom component that depends of two services:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-search-reon',
    templateUrl: './search-reon.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-reon.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        ReonSearchState,
        {
            provide: SEARCH_PARAMETERS_CADNUM,
            useValue: { layers: [335], types: [201, 207], helpSearch: false, searchText: '', searchType: 2 },
        },
        {
            provide: SEARCH_PARAMETERS_ADDRESS,
            useValue: { layers: [335], types: [203], helpSearch: false, searchText: '', searchType: 2 },
        },
        {
            provide: SEARCH_PARAMETERS_UNOM,
            useValue: { layers: [335], types: [202], helpSearch: false, searchText: '', searchType: 2 },
        },
        { provide: SEARCH_CONFIG_CADNUM, useClass: SearchConfig, deps: [SEARCH_PARAMETERS_CADNUM] },
        { provide: SEARCH_CONFIG_ADDRESS, useClass: SearchConfig, deps: [SEARCH_PARAMETERS_ADDRESS] },
        { provide: SEARCH_CONFIG_UNUM, useClass: SearchConfig, deps: [SEARCH_PARAMETERS_UNOM] },
        {
            provide: ReonSearch,
            useFactory: reonServiceFactory,
            deps: [ReonCloudEsService, ReonSearchState],
        },
    ],
})
export class SearchReonComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() searchType: ReonSearchType;
    @Output() onSelected = new EventEmitter<any>();

    public selectedObjectValue: any;
    private reonSearch: ReonSearch;

    constructor(
        @Inject(ReonSearch) public reonServiceFactory: any,
        @Inject(SEARCH_CONFIG_CADNUM) public searchCadnumConfig: SearchConfig,
        @Inject(SEARCH_CONFIG_ADDRESS) public searchAddressConfig: SearchConfig,
        @Inject(SEARCH_CONFIG_UNUM) public searchUnumConfig: SearchConfig,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        try {
            this.factoryReonSearch(this.searchType);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR:' + e);
        }

        this.selectedObject.subscribe((value) => {
            this.selectedObjectValue = value;
        });
    }

    private factoryReonSearch(searchType: ReonSearchType): void {
        switch (searchType) {
            case ReonSearchType.CADNUM:
                this.reonSearch = this.reonServiceFactory(this.searchCadnumConfig, searchType);
                break;
            case ReonSearchType.ADDRESS:
                this.reonSearch = this.reonServiceFactory(this.searchAddressConfig, searchType);
                break;
            case ReonSearchType.UNOM:
                this.reonSearch = this.reonServiceFactory(this.searchUnumConfig, searchType);
                break;
            default:
                throw Error('No provider for search type!');
        }
    }

    public get isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.reonSearch.isLoading;
    }

    public get objects(): Observable<any> {
        return this.reonSearch.objects;
    }

    public get selectedObject(): Observable<any> {
        return this.reonSearch.selectedObject;
    }

    public selectionChange($event: MatSelectChange): void {
        this.reonSearch.setSelectedObject($event.value);
        this.onSelected.emit($event.value);
    }

    public search($event): void {
        this.reonSearch.search($event);
    }
}
```

Only one trigget of event (request to the server) is:

```
   public search($event): void {
        this.reonSearch.search($event);
    }
```

This component has own module:

```
const modules = [CommonModule, MaterialModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgxMatSelectSearchModule];
const components = [SearchReonComponent];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...components],
    imports: [...modules],
    exports: [...components],
    providers: [ReonCloudEsService],
})
export class SearchReonModule {}
```

This module I have imported in dialogs modules where I need to show this component like this:

```
<app-search-reon [searchType]="ReonSearchType.CADNUM"></app-search-reon>
```

As you can see this component use factory to provide `ReonSearch` object in component.

It looks like this:

```
export class ReonSearch {
    public searchEvent = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
    public loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    private cadnums: any[] = [];
    private addresses: any[] = [];
    private unoms: any[] = [];
    private response: any[] = [];

    constructor(
        private reonCloudService: ReonCloudEsService,
        private searchConfig: SearchConfig,
        private searchType: ReonSearchType,
        private reonSearchState: ReonSearchState,
    ) {
        this.searchEvent.pipe(switchMap(() => this.reonCloudService.search(this.searchConfig.parameters))).subscribe(); // REUEST TO SERVER
}
```

Why each time when I open any dialog window where imported `SearchReonModule` I see request to the server in `ReonSearch` on the line:

```
this.reonCloudService.search(this.searchConfig.parameters)
```

Who is pushed event for `this.searchEvent`? Why Angular does not create a separate instancies of `ReonSearch`, `ReonSearchState` for each used component?

**IMPORTANT:**

I have noticed that constructor of `ReonSearch` is called as many times as has been used component in different modules (dialog components).

**MAIN QUESTION:**

Why despite component has provider, Angular does not create a separate instnaces for: `ReonSearch`, `ReonSearchState` inside component:

```
  {
            provide: ReonSearch,
            useFactory: reonServiceFactory,
            deps: [ReonCloudEsService, ReonSearchState],
        },
```

And why one component as effect to others?

Seems I am wrong, I have checked for all components the factory each time works again:

```
export const reonServiceFactory = (reonCloudEsService: ReonCloudEsService, reonSearchState: ReonSearchState) => {
    console.log('works');
}
```

So if I there are two component in tmeplate, I see three times `works`. But what is wrong with `this.searchEvent`? How it has effect to other components?

Comment: I will try to reproduce this in stackBlitz

Comment: Maybe unsubscribe somehow from `this.searchEvent` in constructor?

Comment: Who can explain me how to make isolated components in case when the resuse in different components in template?